# While using Appium to generate protractor scripts, is there a specefic way to locate elements?

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver, protractor, appium, appium-ios

I want to automate my tests using Appium and protractor in an ipad simulator, the problem is that i'm not able to locate by xpath elements, and even if that code is the same generated by Appium. 
I'm always facing this problem :

```
No element found using locator : by.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIAScrollView[1]/UIAScrollView[1]/UIA‌​WebView[1]/UIATextField[1]"))
```

Is there a specefic method for locating elements with protractor and Appium?

Comment: just to help you, you can post this here as well : https://discuss.appium.io/

Comment: Thank you, but i did and no more positive answer that solve my problem : https://discuss.appium.io/t/element-could-not-be-located-in-protractor-scripts-using-appium/9677/13

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer without more information (such as your config file) because there could be a few reasons for this.  In my experience: **no, there is not a specific way of locating elements** (outside of the standard Protractor/webDriver way - by.ID, by.CSS, by.model etc).  More info  here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/locators.md

(1) The obvious - that element doesn't seem to exist at the time of test execution (whether it's because of iPad/safari responsiveness, incorrect xpath, or the tests might be executing before the app has fully loaded)

(2)  Make sure `global.browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` is in your `onPrepare` block of the config file (unless the app is Angular).

(3) In general, I try to avoid using xpath.  There is probably a more robust way of locating that element.  ID's will always be the strongest as they are unique, next I'd suggest CSS chaining such as `var myElement = element(by.css('.parent')).element(by.css('.child')).`  While CSS chaining is very similar to xpath, it gives some freedom and allows you to jump to locators rather than explicitly declaring only a single path for that element like xpath does.

A few of my favorite ways to locate elements:

```
var el = element(by.id('elementID'));
var el2 = element(by.css('.elementClass'))

var el3 = element(by.cssContainingText('div', 'Log In')); 
// returns a div element containing the string 'Log In'

var el4 = element.all(by.css('span.someClass')).first(); 
// .all returns an array of the specific elements, .first() grabs 
// the first from that list, also .last() and others available
```

This article might also be helpful: https://blog.mozilla.org/webqa/2013/09/26/writing-reliable-locators-for-selenium-and-webdriver-tests/

Comment: Thank you very much for you detailed answer, but the problem now i can't run protractor any more :( once the browser (safari) is opened it get closed at time. In case i'm using appium with protractor do i need a safariDriver ? 
Because i get confused now if i make the seleniumAddress: 'http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub' of the one used by appium or i shall change to seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', ==> while i change it, i got the problem that it was failed to connect to safariDriver. So that i ask you if it is necessary ?